UK visa application with an Italian Ricevuta as a non-EU citizen
I have been living in Italy for 6 years and I have a non-EU citizenship. Right now, I only have the ricevuta.
I’ve applied for a UK Skilled Worker visa and one of the documents they require is the proof for my residency in Italy.
Do you have any experience about this? Do they accept ricevuta? And does it have to be translated into English?
Thank you!

Usually, is accepted the ricevuta and the expired residence card
